# Select Sql command Limit?

Tags: php, sql, select

I use

```
select * from table where column = value
```

In php

```
if($result = $db->query("select * from table where column = value"))
{}
```

This returns nothing from table
(JSON result is sent to android app)

but if I append LIMIT 50 to it, it returns 50 records
but not more than that(e.g. 60 returns nothing)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: try to increase max_allowed_packet from mysql configration

Comment: But How do i change this on remote server? where my website is hosted.

Comment: ask who manage your server, if you don't have privilege

Comment: I changed it to max_allowed_packet=128M then 256M but one query works more than 50 but one still does not. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Another thing to mention is that sql in myphpadmin works fine. if thats related.

Comment: do one thing, enable error reporting and check if any error is coming, and once check mysql error log what errors are coming in there

Comment: I found no errors in log :( started error log using  general_log = 1 the log file just shows      Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables      4 Quit (just eg ) for all queries

Comment: this is my config file 

[mysqld]
performance-schema=0
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25165824
open_files_limit=10000
general_log             = 1
slow_query_log = 'ON'; 

Maybe something wrong with this?

Comment: if you select 1 row (LIMIT 1) - how big is the result? (f.e. any TEXT field with HUGE data?)

Comment: LIMIT 1 gives one set(row) of fields (ALL About 10 15 words on average)

Comment: I guess you are using mysqli - any error? see http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples (in use case $db->error)

Comment: Please can you provide real code how do you make query. Also, what if you change `*` to one column? Did it help to get more rows?

Comment: Try to escape value in query if not doing this already, use `$db->escape_string()`

Comment: real string is as such         if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field ='$variable'")){  

(Table name and variable names replaced)

used mysqli_real_escape_string() but it does not make any difference

Comment: Using just one row gives no result. ONLY time it works is when i put LIMIT to it (with *)  (Same query with LIMIT works fine, But not without LIMIT) Another thing to mention is that Similar query on other table works fine without LIMIT (It displays more than 50 rows eg 78rows)

Comment: Selecting ONE ROW works, it shows all rows. But not all data then :(

Comment: Maybe there is a problem encoding result into json? Can you select rows after 50 fist rows using `limiti 50, 50'?

Comment: I m unable to select beyond 54th record (LIMIT 50,4 works gives 4 records LIMIT 50,5 or beyond doesnt give any record)

Comment: If you use an ORDER BY does that change the number of rows that works?

Comment: ORDER BY does not make difference to maximum 54 selection in query

Comment: Total records are 63

Comment: How do you check there is no rows? Do not use json encoding. Just use `echo` and load this page from browser

Comment: I use phpMyadmin to know no of records, it says "Showing rows 0 - 62 (63 total, Query took 0.0016 sec)" to this query without LIMIT

Comment: You said phpMeAdmin works fine. I asking you about your issue - how did you know the result has no rows? Where did you see this? Inside your android app?

Comment: In android App rows load fine as data from server comes. Server doesnt send anything when i do not use LIMIT with select. If i use LIMIT 54 with query, data comes fine and loads fine in android app.

Comment: I know No(zero) rows from catlog in android studio using log.d by displaying json from server

Comment: Ok. Then the problem with encoding data into json. When you try to use json_encode to 54s row it fails.

Comment: I understand your concern but If JSON encoding is wrong, then it shoud not  even work for 54 rows.

Comment: No, it could work. But 54s row contains some data, that can't be encoded because of some reasons. Check the data of this row with phpMyAdmin. Try to skip this row with limit. You'll get results at your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql database contained single inverted comma in row 55 of table which resulted in error. Thanks for everyone's (Hope this inverted comma doesnt spoil up things ;)   ) efforts

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code but with data. If you can get data from your first 54 rows, but on 55th row it fails, and you check this from your android application then the only reason - some error occurs when you encoding data into json. Try to enable php error logging on, and check what error occurs. Also you can check the data with phpMyAdmin - look at 55th row. Anothe way is use php debugging on local machine to check the actual error.

Comment: Finally found the culprit. It was a single inverted comma ( ' ) in data, which results to error in sql select query. This was in row 55. Although everything seemed normal to human eye because its normal to use '  eg Matt's Car.

Comment: Ok, then I think my answer is valid. the problem with data. So you can check it as valid

Comment: Sure Bro, Will award you bounty (Although thats half of all i own:) (in three hours, site restrictions) Thanks a lot